# Passing values between functions and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getjson

I'm having difficulty juggling values in jQuery, as most of jQuery is done in an external script, and I'm not sure when I'm in functions and not in functions, so it's hard to tell when global vars are set and not set.

This one in particular is puzzling me, and I'm absolutely stumped, logically to me it should work, but there seems to be something capping it at some point, and disregarding the values I'm trying to store.

I've concluded this, as the error I'm having is that inside the second getJSON call, I'm getting a 'val' undefined issue, but Javascript console isn't showing any javascript errors, just getting an undefined log when I log to the console and also print the object in an alert.

Just need a fresh set of eyes, feel like this is probably something simple, but I've been looking at the code so long that I can't seem to fathom it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var post_ids = new Array();
var i = 0;
var val;

$.getJSON("/client-ajax/last-ten-posts.php", function(data){
    $.each(data, function(k, val) {
        post_ids.push(val.id);
    });
});

$.getJSON("/client-ajax/last-ten-posts.php?post-id=" + post_ids[0], function(val){
    alert(val.title+"");
    $("#postContainer").empty();
    $("#postContainer").append("<p class='title'>" + val.title + "</p><div class='post-icon'></div><pre>" + val.content + "</pre><p class='footnote'>Posted by " + val.firstname + " " + val.surname + " at <time datetime='2014-06-10'>08:52</time> GMT+00 on the <time>10-06-2014</time></p>");
});
```

UPDATE:

I edited the code slightly in light of @N0ir's answer, but to no success. The done method ensure that actions are taken once the async process is complete, but although this is the case, val is still undefined. The code I've tried is below for examination and dissemination.

```
$.getJSON("/client-ajax/last-ten-posts.php", function(data){
    $.each(data, function(k, val) {
        post_ids.push(val.id);
    });
}).done(function(){
    $.getJSON("/client-ajax/last-ten-posts.php?post-id=" + post_ids[0], function(val){
        alert(val.title+"");
        $("#postContainer").empty();
        $("#postContainer").append("<p class='title'>" + val.title + "</p><div class='post-icon'></div><pre>" + val.content + "</pre><p class='footnote'>Posted by " + val.firstname + " " + val.surname + " at <time datetime='2014-06-10'>08:52</time> GMT+00 on the <time>10-06-2014</time></p>");
    });
});
```

UPDATE - Network Return on call for JSON:

```
GET http://*****************.com/client-ajax/last-ten-posts.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 154ms]
GET http://*****************.com/img/home.jpg [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 152ms]
GET http://*****************.com/img/about.png [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 142ms]
GET http://*****************.com/img/about-repeat.jpg [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 147ms]
GET http://*****************.com/img/blog.jpg [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 146ms]
GET http://*****************.com/img/portfolio.jpg [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 210ms]
GET http://*****************.com/img/contact.jpg [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 209ms]
GET http://*****************.com/client-ajax/last-ten-posts.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 207ms]
```

Comment: Logically it __should not__ work, because `$.getJSON` is __ASYNCHRONOUS__.

Comment: your `last-ten-posts` service should just return the full posts, or as much as you need to display. Making two calls seems needlessly expensive.

Comment: It's actually less expensive as I'm returning and gathering based on ID's rather than collecting a ridiculously large amount of data on that first call, I only retrieve the ID's of all blog posts, and then collect them as I shuffle through the ID's. Much more bandwidth friend, which is what the key aim in web development is, computers are more powerful these days, but ISP's are still slowing us down, especially in the UK.

Comment: May I add, that the necessity of this is due to code that is present after this small excerpt, but this is more relevant to the problem and is the only necessary part. I know you're just trying to help, but I've thought this through.

Comment: Are you actually stepping through this code with the debugger? Are you checking to make sure `/client-ajax/last-ten-posts.php?post-id=[id]` actually returns something?

Comment: Everything has been checked, including the PHP script. I've been stepping through the debugger all night. Please suggest actual solutions, this is not a simple problem clearly. There is an issue to do with inference somewhere.

Comment: So if you just run that second `$.getJSON` block with an explicit ID, does it work? (Also keep in mind that SO is not a debugging service, I/we don't owe you anything, and nothing you've posted in your question so far suggests you actually know what you're doing, so don't get upset when I want to make sure you've covered all your bases.)

Comment: I'm not offended, your answers just seem very generic. Like you haven't really assessed it, pretty frowned upon here surely, no? Also I never said you owe me anything, feel free to stop posting, I'm asking for an answer and you chose to respond, you subjected yourself. So please calm yourself, and provide a solution or leave it.

Comment: Based on what you've said, `val` isn't undefined, `val.title` is; you need to throw a `console.log(val)` at the top of that callback to see what you're getting back (or check the response on the call in the Network tab of the console.) The only way `val` could be undefined is if your service returns a `200` along with an empty response. The code you're showing doesn't have any scoping issues that I can see. I don't think it's unreasonable to request you to confirm the due diligence in debugging a problem; there are no apparent issues in your code since the update.

Comment: Using the console log I get "ReferenceError: val is not defined"

Comment: So that means your service isn't returning anything, but is still returning `200` (otherwise it would error.) Can you confirm that you are getting a JSON payload back from the request in the network tab?

Comment: Just updated the post at the bottom with network info.

Comment: You're missing my point. It's obviously returning `200` but what is the response payload? If it's _nothing_, that's why the response is undefined in your success callback.

Comment: How do I find out that information?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I found the issue, turns out fetchAll() in php's PDO returns an array, so when creating the JSON from the array, the JSON needs to be accessed through the first element of the array, like so:

```
val[0].content
```

rather than:

```
val.content
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `$.getJSON`, it simply receives what your service sends back; your _service_ is returning an array.

Comment: Yeh, it was because I was using fetchAll() with PDO rather than solely fetch(), as fetchAll() returns the array of results and if there's only one result it still puts it in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You wanna do somethign like this:

```
var post_ids = new Array();
var i = 0;
var val;

$.getJSON("/client-ajax/last-ten-posts.php", function(data){
    $.each(data, function(k, val) {
        post_ids.push(val.id);
    });
    $.getJSON("/client-ajax/last-ten-posts.php?post-id=" + post_ids[0], function(result){
        alert(result.title+"");
        $("#postContainer").empty();
        $("#postContainer").append("<p class='title'>" + result.title + "</p><div class='post-icon'></div><pre>" + result.content + "</pre><p class='footnote'>Posted by " + result.firstname + " " + result.surname + " at <time datetime='2014-06-10'>08:52</time> GMT+00 on the <time>10-06-2014</time></p>");
    });
});
```

So that the second getJSON call happens after the first one is finished.

Comment: where does `val.title` come from? It's undefined

Comment: @charlietfl I think it's pretty clear that `val.title` is a typo of `data.title`, also present in OP's question.

Comment: I just copypasted OP's code, I am not sure what val.title is... Could it be that he actually meant data.title?

Comment: Edited the answer, using `result` instead of `data` so not to confuse first `data` with the second `data`

Comment: ignore val right now, the code doesn't make it that far, it fails before that, so I haven't changed it as of yet, I was dabbling with the different var names.

Comment: @N0ir Yeh, you're solution didn't work unfortunately :/ Still getting the same problem.